# if and else-if statements refuses to work in jquery's ajax function

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that is called when a button is clicked, this function sends an ajax request using jquery. On success I have some logical if and else if statements. The web server can only send 2 types of text responses. It can either be "Success" or "Error". But when testing for these two conditions they seem to fail. I have added an else statement and an alert to tell me what the server is sending but just as I expected, it is either "Success" or "Error", the way I programmed my servlet in the server, it can only send "Success" or "Error" as response. Moreover my alert is spitting out "Success" or "Error" please I dont understand what is wrong here. please help.

```
 function deleteRecord(productID, description)
 {
    var errorMessage = '<td class="red-left">There was an error. <a href="">Please try again.</a></td>';
    var successMessage = '<td class="green-left">Product '+productID+' ('+description+') has been deleted sucessfully.</td>';
    var data = "productID="+productID+"&description="+description+"&deleteProduct=true";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "deleteInventoryRecord.mpcs",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(info)
        {
            if(info == 'Success')//This does not work
            {
                $(".green-left").replaceWith(successMessage);
                $("#message-green").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#product-"+productID).remove();
            }
            else if(info == 'Error')//This does not work
            {
                $(".red-left").replaceWith(errorMessage);
                $("#message-red").fadeIn("slow");
            } 
            else//This works always but I dont need it
            {
                alert(info); //It always says "Success" or "Error"
            }
        },
        dataType: 'text'
    });
 }
```

Here is the servlet code that sends the response:

```
private void deleteProduct(HttpServletResponse response, String productID) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        InventoryDAO iDao = new InventoryDAO();
        if(iDao.deleteProduct(productID) == true)
            response.getWriter().println("Success");
        else
            throw new RuntimeException("Error");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException | IOException | SQLException | RuntimeException xcp)
    {
        response.getWriter().println("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: how does the `deleteInventoryRecord.mpcs` look like?

Comment: You sure there are no spaces or hidden characters in the response? Have you tried $.trim(info)

Comment: Is it possible that you're returning a value with leading or trailing spaces, or non-printing characters, and a different text case?

Comment: do you want me to show you the code? It is a java servlet.

Comment: Most likely `info` is not equal to *"Success"*. `console.log(info)` will help us help you solve this.

Comment: I have added the servlet code please take a look

Comment: You may be able to fix this with an extra hint on the content type: `response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");`

Comment: Does `println()` also add `\n\r` at the end of line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to take a shot in the dark here, and say that the server is sending the response in UTF8 with a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark), and this is causing your comparisons to fail.

To confirm, try `alert(info.length)`. It should be 7 for "Success" or 5 for "Error". If it is not, then you probably have a BOM.

Another thing to check of course is that there is no whitespace in the response - again, the `length` check will help verify this.

You can fix this by encoding your server-side scripts as "UTF8 without BOM", sometimes referred to as "ANSI as UTF8" depending on your editor. Alternatively, change your `if` blocks to:

```
if( info.match(/Success$/)) ...
else if( info.match(/Error$/)) ...
```

Comment: I have tried alert(info.length) . it gave me 9 for "Success" and 7 for "Error" but I dont understand why.

Comment: The BOM is two characters. It's as I suspected ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your `deleteProduct` method sets content type "text/html", but you are sending plain text. This is likely to confuse jQuery, as it tries to guess the type of `info` based on the content type header sent. Either use "text/plain", or even better "application/json", so you may sent more info to the client.